# Nuxt2 vs Nuxt3 performance?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Recently I was investigating the performance of two frameworks. I found that the performance gap between the two is very big. I used the simplest demo to run [JMeter](https://github.com/apache/jmeter).

Nuxt2:
[image]

Nuxt3:
[image]

I can't believe that the performance gap between the two is so much. Is it a problem with my code or operation?

Comment: How did you test it? Could u show the code?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what is written here in Chinese (or else), but Nuxt3 uses Vue3 so it should indeed be faster than Nuxt2 which uses Vue2, nothing shocking/special here.

PS: I'm expecting Nuxt3 to be better than Nuxt2.

Also, synthetic benchmarks can always be tricky to properly design and get some really clean/simple comparison especially with hydration etc...

Otherwise, if it's the opposite (Nuxt3 is worse), it probably have to do with the fact that it's still in Release Candidate. But so far, without any really specific code or another benchmark, we will not be able to help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that nuxt3 is definitely better than nuxt2, otherwise there is no need to update, hhhh. But the results I tested, the performance has basically doubled, which is what surprised me.

Comment: The Vue core team did a lot of upgrades regarding the compilation, the way the shadow DOM is handled, the amount of runtime memory used etc...so it's totally legit. Check some talks of Evan You on YouTube if you want to get more details. Feel free to drop a `thanks` on the Vue discord if you appreciate the performance gains! @Zachary

Comment: Hahaha, brother, your answer is very official, I joined the discord of vue and nuxt.I know these updates, but what bothers me is that I prefer to use nuxt2 in prod, and nuxt3 feels less stable to me.

Comment: @Zachary Nuxt3 is not that unstable, it can be used for some projects already. And Nuxt2 may be slower, but it will probably not be seen in real world scenario, like if you load some Google analytics or a fat image, you will be far beyond those performance gains overall. So it depends on your project, but there is no real answer to give here per-se haha.

Comment: @Zachary anything else that you wish me to answer or is it all good?

Comment: Nope, thanks a lot, I just wanted to confirm if there is such a big performance difference between the two.